# The name of the class that "newed" my class

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, is there a way to get the name of the class that creates an instance of MyClass?

I know that I could pass it in as an argument on my initialize method, but I want to know if any data is already there that has to do with the class that created an instance of MyClass in side of MyClass.

So it would be like

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @who_called_me = who_called_me.name
  end

  def who_called_me
    puts @who_called_me
  end
end
```

Comment: If you need to know that, there's probably something wrong with your design.

Comment: Generally, I can think of no simple way to do this. But you can get a string of the stack backtrace and parse it for the frame before the call to `new`. That might give you the part of the code that called `new`. But that would make your code dependent on the formatting of a stack backtrace. Not a good thing.

Comment: This is a special case, but thanks for questioning my design, it really helps

Comment: I added an answer doing what I suggested above. I have not tested it yet, but I will.

Comment: Not all classes have names, `c = Class.new; puts c.name` for example. Granted, this is a pathological case but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is not portable between implementations and versions, this is a crude solution:

```
who_made_me=caller[3].split(':')[1][4..-2]
```

What this does is it gets the current stack, skips the strings for `initialize`, `allocate`, and `new`, and then gets the method name out of the string. Again, this is a total hack, and is based around unspecified behavior. I would not suggest using this unless *absolutely* necessary.

Comment: You da man!!!  This is some messed up code but don't worry it is so worth it. Some people are in a rrobots friendly comp and let's say I need to protect my class from being created by so

Comment: @Loren, you can't reliably protect against any other class creating you, because in ruby, they can just rewrite the part of your class that protects against it, by reopening the class.

Comment: @LorenCFortner: If it helps, you can try writing the protection code as a C function that is called from an extension. Ruby can't override C functions.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is evil. I've seen an equivalent in C#, but it produced violently cruel side effects, not to mention ugly-as-heck code.

In Ruby, if you really had to do this, you'd probably start with Kernel.caller. But please don't do that.

Comment: I posted something that *might* work using `Kernel#caller` bellow. It is a complete hack, and I agree with you, but it is an answer.

Comment: "violently cruel side effects" - please tell more!

Comment: @Andrew, Basically, since other code couldn't predict the behavior of the constructor, it had special cases, and so it broke all of the OOP rules; I've seen an even worse example in Perl where the parameters were parsed differently depending on the caller.