# Ruby - Can an object access or identify the object which instantiated it?

Tags: ruby

For example, how could I implement the following:

```
class A
  def initialize
    b = B.new
  end
end

class B
  def initialize
   puts #how can I find out who instantiated me
  end
end
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720677/the-name-of-the-class-that-newed-my-class/8720780#8720780).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A
  def initialize
    B.new(self)
  end
end

class B
  def initialize initializer
    puts initializer
  end
end

A.new # => #<A:0x007fee78368dc8>
```

Comment: Is there anyway for Class B to access it's "creator" object without self being explicitly passed?

Comment: Maybe you can play around with `TracePoint`. But I don't see any reason for doing that, and I would not do that.